# What to use instead of android.app.action.ENTER_CAR_MODE in API 26

Tags: android

Starting with Oreo, Android forbidden use of implicit broadcast receivers in Manifest and adviced to register receiver at runtime and or use JobSchedule instead. There is a list of some exceptions as well, however I cannot find an acceptable answer to my situation.

I have a service which runs in the background only when the phone is in CAR mode, up till now I use this to determine when the device entered/exited the car mode and started/stopped the service accordingly:

```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.app.action.ENTER_CAR_MODE"/>
           <action android:name="android.app.action.EXIT_CAR_MODE" />
       </intent-filter>
```

I had a look in the JobSchedule builder but I cannot find anything which relates to CAR, only to charging, network type, and other irrelevant stuff for my case.

How I'm supposed to tackle this?

Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you tested your app for Android 26? I think you don't need to change anything, the intents you are using have not been blocked by the new rules

Comment: I've tested and they are blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your needs

> A service which starts when the device goes into car mode and ends when he leaves it without having the user watching at your application (so without opened activities)

is probably the type of things Google wanted to avoid with the new API 26 restrictions to prevent battery drains. Entering and exiting the car mode should produce only a change of the UI if the user is watching your app while doing this.

You could create a `JobScheduler` and run it at X minutes interval to check for the actual device condition with `UiModeManager#getCurrentModeType()` and start a foreground service if the condition is met, but this is a lot far from your current behaviour and the user will be notified of this by a fixed notification.

Comment: There is no activity just a service which is supposed to start automatically when the user enters car mode. It's ok to register it at runtime, but since it's a service it won't ever get to run in the first place...

Comment: Well that isn't really an option and sorry but in my head it's unclear how repetitively checking against conditions every X minutes is more power efficient then only executing it when a given condition is met. If there is no realistic alternative I will have to stick with targeting version 25 which works as expected.

Comment: [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html) is managed by the system, it is launched in an efficient way and with it you can't be exactly precise on when the job will run. And for sure running a method every 10 minutes it's more efficient than running a service for indefinitive minutes ^^. For the second part of your comment, you will need to fight against [this new policy](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) which will be introduced next year

Comment: Nice blog, well my app is not even allowed on Play Store because at the minute they say Android Auto compatible apps are limited to partners only. As of what I'm doing I think you have miss-understand it. The app is a service which runs in the background and provide additional information for Android Auto. There is no UI as such in the app, neither an activity, all I have is a service which starts when phone enters car mode and stops when it exit the car mode, so running a method each X minutes still sound more task heavy then executing a method on a receiver.

Comment: An app which is only a "background service" which "provide additional information for Android Auto" to who? I don't know, maybe you need to re-think how you have structured it. BTW I think I've answered your question, actually as far as I know it's not possible to do what you want based on your requirements on API 26+. Good luck man :)